# Why is my tensorflow Roberta Model unable to train/finetune?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, roberta-language-model

We are trying to finetune / train our RoBERTa model on our own train data. The project is exactly the same as the SemEval-2020 task B on choosing the right reason out of 3 on why a sentence is against common sense. For the past two days we have been struggling with errors, mainly when trying to train/finetune our model. The code we have used comes from https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/roberta.html#robertamodel . Although we have tried to alter this code in multiple ways we can't seem to really start training our model. Our main problem is the data we try to train the model on. We have tried to immediately insert a numpy array or pandas dataframe, but to no avail. Finally we tried to use a tfds. We used the following code, which results in the error code which can be found below.

I install the following packages:

```
# Modules
pip install transformers
from transformers import RobertaConfig, RobertaModel
from transformers import RobertaTokenizer, RobertaForMultipleChoice
from transformers import AutoModel, AutoTokenizer
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np # linear algebra
import pandas as pd # data processing, CSV file I/O (e.g. pd.read_csv)
import os
```

I import my train and test sets as csv files, where after the data is cleaned and concatenated.

```
# Read csv files
sample_data = pd.read_csv("sample.csv")
train_data = pd.read_csv("train_data.csv")
train_answers = pd.read_csv("train_answers.csv")
test_data = pd.read_csv("test_data.csv")
train_data['A_concat'] = train_data['FalseSent'] + '. ' + train_data['OptionA']
train_data['B_concat'] = train_data['FalseSent'] + '. ' + train_data['OptionB']
train_data['C_concat'] = train_data['FalseSent'] + '. ' + train_data['OptionC']
train_data.drop(['OptionA','OptionB','OptionC'],axis=1,inplace=True)
train_data.columns = ['id', 'FalseSent', 'OptionA', 'OptionB', 'OptionC']
```

I make a tfds of the train and test data:

```
tf_train_data = tf.data.experimental.CsvDataset("train_data.csv", record_defaults='Tensor', header=True)
tf_test_data = tf.data.experimental.CsvDataset("test_data.csv", record_defaults='Tensor', header=True)
```

These data sets are then used to train the model through the following code:

```
from transformers import TFRobertaForMultipleChoice, TFTrainer, TFTrainingArguments

model = TFRobertaForMultipleChoice.from_pretrained("roberta-base")

training_args = TFTrainingArguments(
    output_dir='./results',          
    num_train_epochs=3,              
    per_device_train_batch_size=16,  
    per_device_eval_batch_size=64,   
    warmup_steps=500,                
    weight_decay=0.01,               
    logging_dir='./logs',            
)

trainer = TFTrainer(
    model=model,                        
    args=training_args,                 
    train_dataset=tf_train_data,    
    eval_dataset=tf_test_data       
)

trainer.train()
```

This results in the following error:

**ValueError: The training dataset must have an asserted cardinality**

If anybody has any advice or can point us in the right direction on how to train/finetune our model we would be very grateful!

Comment: what is your training dataset shape ?

Comment: 7997 rows x 4 columns.
The columns being 'id', 'OptionA', 'OptionB', 'OptionC'.

Comment: And the three options are concatenated, so the false sentence + the reason.

Comment: please get shape `print(tf_train_data.take(1))` and add to the question

Comment: <TakeDataset shapes: ((), (), (), (), (), ()), types: (tf.string, tf.string, tf.string, tf.string, tf.string, tf.string)>

is the output.

Answer (score 0):

You should feed sequences of integers (tf.int) to Roberta not tf.string. Tokenize your data

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I have tokenized the sentences, however I can't convert it to a tf.dataset using the following code:


`
features= ['OptionA', 'OptionB', 'OptionC']

training_dataset = (
    tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
        (
            tf.cast(train_data[features].values, tf.float64),
            tf.cast(train_data['Answer'].values, tf.int32)
        )
    )
)
`

Python gives the error: "ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type list)."

Comment: I believe the biggest problem is that tf.data.Dataset can't take a list as an input, or at least won't accept list as a viable datatype.

Comment: @SamV try `for a in training_dataset: print(a)`

Comment: Where do I try that exactly? Since I can not make the training_dataset

Comment: @SamV I mean `tf_train_data ` not `training_dataset`. Try before calling TFTrainer

Comment: I have now tried it in another way which seems to work when creating datasets, but it lead me to another error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65274777/how-to-encode-string-in-tf-data-dataset 

This way I can use a dataframe to load a tf.dataset. Is this a solution or is the old way of loading via csv file better? I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @SamV I can not help here - I didn't work with dataframes, tf.strings, Huggingface tokenizers