# How to encode string in tf.data.Dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tokenize

So I am trying to encode a string in a tensorflow dataset in order to use it to train a pretrained RoBERTa model.
The training_dataset is a tensorflow dataset made from a pandas dataframe that looks like this:
[image]

I used this dataframe to construct the tf.data.Dataset using:

```
features = ['OptionA', 'OptionB', 'OptionC']

training_dataset = (
    tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
        (
            tf.cast(train_split[features].values, tf.string),
            tf.cast(train_split['Answer'].values, tf.int32)
        )
    )
)
```

Now I want to encode the 3 columns OptionA, OptionB and Option C using a RobertaTokenizer, which is defined by:

```
tokenizer = RobertaTokenizer.from_pretrained("roberta-base")
```

I tried:

```
training_dataset = training_dataset.map(lambda x: tokenizer.encode(x))
```

But this gave me the error: "TypeError: () takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given" and I am not sure how to deal with this or how to state that I only want the first three columns to be encoded.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

`training_dataset` has features and outputs, and in your `map` function, you're only using one variable. Try:

```
training_dataset = training_dataset.map(lambda x, y: (tokenizer.encode(x), y))
```